# Ordenar números em uma session?

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela onde os usuários selecionam vários números e são gravados em uma `$_SESSION`, ate ai tudo bem, só que preciso que estes números apareçam em ordem crescente:

Exemplo da `$_SESSION gravada = 22-20-38-54-52-42-34-18-70-75`

Preciso que apareça assim `= 18-20-22-34-38-42-52-54-70-75`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça o seguinte, transforme essa string em um array, depois ordene o array da forma que desejar e por fim converta o array em uma string separado pelo caracter que você desejar.

```
$_SESSION['numbers'] = '22-20-38-54-52-42-34-18-70-75';
$array_numbers = explode( '-', $_SESSION['numbers'] ); // Quebra a string em um array

sort( $array_numbers ); // Ordena o array em ordem crescente

$numbers = implode( '-', $array_numbers ); // Quebra do array em string, separando por "-"

print_r( $numbers ); // Vai imprimir o seguinte resultado: 18-20-22-34-38-42-52-54-70-75
```